# Can't find an Amazon DynamoDB database after creating it programmatically

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I created an Amazon DynamoDB database using the code from the following documentation:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html

But when I go to my account->DynamoDB->Tables, I don't see any tables made, why is that?

When I tried the code for checking table creation time, it returns good value(time when I really ran the code for creating it), also when I tried running same code again, it showed 'table with the same name already exists' error.

Comment: Did you check that you are searching in the correct region?

Comment: You were right! It's all solved, thanks a lot!